# phpでアクセス先のphpにPOSTでバイナリデータを送信したいです

Tags: php

Client.php → Server.php へデータをPOSTでデータを送信したいです。 
送信するデータは AAA=1とBBB=2とファイルから読み込んだバイナリデータです。 
その際、Wiresharkで送信データを見る時、「bina.bin(中身のバイナリはFB EE FB EFとします)と同じバイナリデータが表示されていてほしいです。formは使えません。

ver1のClient.phpのプログラムを示します。

```
// 送信データファイル読み込み
$SendContents = file_get_contents("C:/xampp/htdocs/bina.bin");
//POSTデータ
$data = array(
    "AAA" => "1",
    "BBB" => "2",
    "BinData" => $SendContents
    );
$data = http_build_query($data, "", "&");
$header = array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)
);
$context = array(
    "http" => array(
        "method"  => "POST",
        "header"  => implode("\r\n", $header),
        "content" => $data
    )
);
// アクセスする先
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/Server.php";
file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($context));
```

上記のコードでは%エンコードされているようでして、Wiresharkに「FB EE FB EF」のデータが出ませんでした。

```
ver2のClient.phpのプログラムを示します。
$SendContents = file_get_contents("C:/xampp/htdocs/bina.bin");
//POSTデータ
$data = array(
    "AAA" => "1",
    "BBB" => "2",
    "BinData" => "$SendContents"
    );
$header = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream";
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => $header,
        'content' => $data,//←直接"$SendContents"を入れると上手くいく
        )
    );
// アクセスする先
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/Server.php";
file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

ver2のコードですと、上手く送信ができません。 
'content' => $SendContents にするとWiresharkにはバイナリデータ「FB EE FB EF」が表示されますが、POSTで AAA=1 と BBB=2も送信したいと思っております。 
ここからどうすれば良いかご教授願いたいです。 
宜しくお願い致します。

xampp 
Apache 
php 
Wireshark

追記
サーバーのプログラムを示します。
echo $_POST["AAA"];
echo $_POST["BBB"];
echo $_POST["$data"];
です

Comment: >上記のコードでは%エンコードされているようでして、Wiresharkに「FB EE FB EF」のデータが出ませんでした。 とありますが、この時点で何が問題なのでしょうか……パーセントエンコーディングはサーバー側でデコードしていれば問題ないのでは？ まあバイナリ送るのであれば`multipart/form-data`  とか使うべきかもしれませんが……

Comment: hinaloe様 ご回答ありがとうございます。通信時にバイナリデータが出てほしいです。「multi〜」試してみます。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/56464

Comment: htb様　同じ質問することはマナー違反だったのですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。申し訳ございません。

Comment: multi～試しましたが、AAABBBの部分がWiresharkで表示されませんでした。ストリームを使用して作成してみてみようと思います。

Comment: `multipart/form-data` で送信すると次の画像のようになります→ https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRppP.png AAA=1 を送りつつ「FB EE FB EF」もそのまま表示されています。これが意図した表示でないなら、Wiresharkのどこにどんな形で表示されるか言葉で説明していただくか、スクリーンショットに描きこんで、具体的に示してもらえませんか？ひょっとして [`Form item: "AAA" = "1"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWrij.png) といった形にバイナリも含めたいのであれば、それは不可能です。

Comment: また、Wiresharkでバイナリをそのまま表示してほしい、というのはあまり聞かない話なので、その理由を教えてもらえれば代替策を提示できるかもしれません。